# AJAX xmlhttp.send() not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm a complete and utter AJAX noob and have been sitting with the same problem for the last 5 hours.

My script code

```html
<script language='javascript'>
function upvote(id ,username)
{   
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
        {
            
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "vote.php?id=" +id+"&username=" +username, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

My onclick link,

```html
<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='upvote($id,$username)'></a>
```

`$_GET` is used to retrieve parameters sent via the URL of the page. For example

```
../vote.php?id=3&username=anor
```

My php file works perfect when i tried that.

I don't think there's anything wrong with the PHP anyway. For some reason however, xmlhttp.send(params) is still not sending the required variables to the vote.php file. I tried post AJAX request but it didn't work either.

Comment: Can't pass php variables to a javascript function. Show how link is generated in php. Need to echo actual values

Comment: Also note errors thrown in browser console

Comment: There is not any problem in .php file . I just couldn't send my variables to my script and my .php file.

Comment: $id and $username seem to be PHP variables. Did you check how the resulting HTML looks like in your browser? Make sure that string values get surrounded by quotes in Javascript (e.g. if $username was a string and $id an integer,  it should be `$id, "$username"`)

Comment: because they do not appear to be JavaScript variables ... show how link html is generated. javscript and php run in different places at different times

Comment: I used these variables hundred of times in html browser they works perfect . Just not inside of onclick()

Comment: Did you read and understand my comment? Did you even check the *resulting* browser HTML? Please show us!

Comment: What does the Javascript console tell you? Did you try to debug (F12) in your browser?

Comment: can you please say me first does my ajax script look fine or not ? I think there is a mistake in there . What do you mean "check resulting browser HTML" ? I checked my variables in browse they looks fine .

Comment: onclick="upvote(127,anor)"

Comment: I said they send my variables to onclick function but there is a problem in script code .

Comment: Why are you so reluctant in showing us the resulting HTML code from your browser instead of the PHP part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit them
If php file

```
$id = '1';
$username = 'suman';

echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="upvote(\''$id'\',\''$username'\')"></a>';
?>
```

Comment: so? What...does...your...resulting...HTML...look...like?

Comment: nevermind i spent my last 8 hours with these problem . I gave up . Thank you for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

If this is part of your PHP code

```
onclick='upvote($id, $username)'
```

it won't work. It should be

```
onclick='upvote($id, "$username")'
```

instead. Let's see the example that you posted: $id=3 and $username=anor. This would result in

```
onclick='upvote(3, anor)'
```

As long as there is no Javascript variable with the name `anor`, this would be equivalent to

```
onclick='upvote(3, undefined)'
```

Do you get that?

PS: The upvote function itself seems to be fine

Comment: It didn't work . I tried onclick='upvote($id, "$username")' and onclick='upvote($id, \"$username\")' and onclick='upvote($id, '$username')'   and all of them didn't work